# Xenu slash redirection

Tags: asp.net, seo, xenu

I am using my website to check the broken links with Xenu and it is not interpreting the server side  redirection properly.

I have build my website using asp.net and used server side direction as follows
Client is redirected from this page

> http://mysite.com/ordermanagement/ordersequence/OrderFormRedirector.aspx

to /signup/newclientsignup.aspx?pt=0&pkc=0&pkt=0 from server side which rendered as

> http://mysite.com/signup/newclientsignup.aspx?pt=0&pkc=0&pkt=0

but Xenu interpret it as follows

> http://mysite.com/ordermanagement/ordersequence/%2fsignup%2fnewclientsignup.aspx%3fpt=0&pkc=0&pkt=0

Comment: what is you question?
Xenu is old tool thats not supported any more by the program builders

Comment: I just want to avoid those broken links as they are being shown in the final report

Comment: Crawl the website with the beta version there is a chance that this bug got fixed get it from here http://home.snafu.de/tilman/tmp/xenubeta.zip